# In skobbler 3.0 how to set a custom image in an annotation on a map

Tags: android, android-studio, skobbler-maps

The new library, the class SKAnnotation not have the method:

annotation.setImagePath (mImagePath);

Answer (score 0):

Please use code like the following

```
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(itemId);
annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(lat, lon));    
SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
RelativeLayout customView = (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
               R.layout.layout_custom_pin, null, false);
annotationView.setView(customView);
annotation.setAnnotationView(annotationView);    
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
```